# How can put my JTextField on a vertial alignment

Tags: java, jtextfield, vertical-alignment

i don't know how to write a jtextfield on a vertical alignment, i can't find in the alignment option. Thanks

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: To write a word in vertical

Comment: Suppose String "A B C D" in a column with single row?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584463/how-do-i-align-text-within-a-jtextfield

Comment: no, that's for a JtextArea, i'm using JtextField

Comment: JTextField is when you only need one line. User name and password fields for example.

Comment: You need to use JTextArea

Answer (score 0):

`JTextField` is when you only need one line. User name and password fields for example.

`JTextArea` is when you need multiple rows.

See [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/154935-how-to-set-vertical-position-of-text-in-a-texfield/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584463/how-do-i-align-text-within-a-jtextfield)

There is no way to make `JTextField` vertical see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

So, I am suggesting you to use `JTextArea`